# Load environment variables from file just for the next script

Tags: bash

I have one of those `.env` files with several variables set, like:

```
VAR1=111
VAR2=222
```

I want to run a script (without changing it) that makes use of those variables. 
I know I can `source` that file in the shell and export the variables from the file, like:

```
set -a
source myenvs.env   # this is my .env file
set +a
./myscript.sh  # this will use the variables
```

The problem with that is it loads all those variables in my shell, which I don't want (shell pollution.)

What I'm looking for is the equivalent of using `env VAR1=111 VAR2=222 ./myscript.sh` but getting those variables from the .env file instead.

Comment: Why not `source .env` in your myscript.sh?

Comment: @Roadowl The truth is I need to keep that script flexible to run with different combinations of settings. Imagine I have several .env files like _development.env_, _stagin.env_, _repro-bug-123.env_, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do that in a subshell and main shell's environment won't be altered. E.g:

```
(
  set -a
  source myenvs.env   # this is my .env file
  exec ./myscript.sh  # avoid unnecessary fork()
)
```

> The truth is I need to keep that script flexible to run with different combinations of settings. Imagine I have several .env files like development.env, stagin.env, repro-bug-123.env, etc.

A function would be more useful in that case.

```
with_env() (
  set -a
  source "$1"
  shift
  exec "$@"
)

with_env myenvs.env ./myscript.sh
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly it! I had _just now_ found a way to make it work with `bash -c "set -a; source ./myenvs.env; set +a; ./myscript.sh"` but your suggestion is what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Declare vars that you don't want to change as read only

```
declare -r VAR3 VAR4
```

and source the rest

```
. ./myenvs.env
```